# Reference a jar or compile it with Dalvik?

Tags: android, dalvik

I have a jar that I need to reference from my Android project. I also have the src of the jar, so I could include it in the project itself. I was wondering if referencing a jar vs. compiling it in with the project using Dalvik makes any difference in terms of final Dalvik package size that gets generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ant to build your project, just include the .jar file in your `libs/` directory. The build script will automatically include it in your APK.

Answer (score 0):

Including source file or referring .jar file doesn't make much difference in size. Both are ultimately converted to Dalvic Executables(.dex).